# syntax error near unexpected token `(' when defining function in bash profile

Tags: bash, function, alias

```
gac() {
        git add .
        git commit -m "$1"
}
```

This function is in my bash profile, and it raises an error when I try to source the file.

```
$ source ~/.bashrc
bash: /home/sahandz/.bashrc: line 176: syntax error near unexpected token `('
bash: /home/sahandz/.bashrc: line 176: `gac() {'
```

I can't figure out why. I have another function that looks like this and doesn't raise any error:

```
abcToTestDir() {
        folderName=${1%_*}
        testFolderPath="$testfilespath$folderName"
        abcFilePath="$abcpath$folderName/$1"
        testFilePath="$testFolderPath/$1"

        mkdir -p $testFolderPath
        cp $abcFilePath $testFilePath
}
```

What is wrong with my function definition?

Comment: What's in the other 175 lines before `gac() {`?

Comment: Works for me in `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: Your function is fine. That means something prior to that is wrong.

Answer (score 6):

This can happen if `gac` is already an alias. For example on my machine:

```
$ type ls
ls is aliased to `ls --color=auto'
$ ls(){ true; }
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Comment: Thanks, `gac` was an alias in my previous bash profile and it wasn't removed simply by removing the appropriate line from .bashrc. Running `unalias gac` and then `source ~/.bashrc` did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

[The existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56408356/syntax-error-near-unexpected-token-when-defining-function-in-bash-profile#56408400) is correct. This answer is to provide more information.

When you define a function with the POSIX syntax (like `ls()`) *after* defining the alias, Bash expands the alias *before* parsing your function definition. In other words, your function definition becomes

```bash
ls --color=auto() {
    true
}
```

which is why you saw the error message. This behavior is mentioned in [this post](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/issues/6723#issuecomment-381220834) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76638009/zsh-script-is-throwing-a-syntax-error-parse-error-near). In your case, you ended up unaliasing it because you didn't need it; but for the one who wishes to keep both (people coming from search engines), there are two more options:

1. Use the new-style function definition with the `function` keyword, like `function ls() { ... }`. This breaks the portability, though (if you care about that).
2. Define the alias *after* the function. (Or temporarily save the alias, define the function, then restore the alias.)