# zsh script is throwing a syntax error: `parse error near `()'`

Tags: shell, zsh

I am using Mac OS and zsh terminal.
When I am running my file I am getting this error on my terminal.

```
/file/path/.git_alias:10: defining function based on alias `gss'
/file/path/.git_alias:10: parse error near `()'
```

Can someone help me why I am getting this error?

Here is my file name and file content.

file name: `.git_alias`

file content:

```bash
alias gsl='git stash list'

gsa() {
    local num
    num=$1
    shift 1 || return
    git stash apply stash@{"${num}"} "$@";
}

gss() {
    local comment
    comment=$1
    shift 1 || return
    git stash save -u "${comment}" "$@";
}
```

I tried to look for bash syntax and tried to add and remove `"` at appropriate places but I am still getting the same error mentioned above.

Comment: Why the `{}` in the following line: `git stash apply stash@{"${num}"} "$@";`.

Comment: Are you using `bash` or `zsh`? Or are you trying to use `bash` syntax in `zsh`?

Comment: if you're using `zsh` ... why is the question tagged with `bash` and not `zsh`?

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1369319/getting-defining-function-based-on-alias-z-error-everytime-open-the-terminal

Comment: The error happens because you already defined an alias named `gss`. Using that syntax to redefine it as a function gets that error. You should get rid of the alias definition.

Comment: @Barmar that solution does not help me that's why I posted.

I have several other scripts as well with the same syntax but only this file is throwing an error.

Comment: @SoulDenied, also, note that just deleting the alias definition from the file and re-source'ing the file doesn't delete the alias -- it's still there in any interpreter that sourced the file back when the file _did_ contain a conflicting alias definition.

Comment: In zsh, you can type a plain `alias`, to get a list of aliases present at this time. Use this to check what aliases you have here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you already have an alias named `gss`, that's what the first warning is telling you.

The syntax error happens because when it sees a line beginning with `gss`, it expands the alias. After that, the braces for holding the function body are no longer valid syntax.

If you can't find where that alias is being defined and remove it, you have two options in this file:

Remove the alias first:

```
unalias gss
gss() {
    local comment
    comment=$1
    shift 1 || return
    git stash save -u "${comment}" "$@";
}
```

or use the alternative syntax for defining the function:

```
function gss {
    local comment
    comment=$1
    shift 1 || return
    git stash save -u "${comment}" "$@";
}
```

A third option is to rename the function or alias, so they don't conflict.

Comment: Changing the name of the alias helped me out. But can you tell me, How I can see the previous command under `gss` alias. I can't unalias the `gss` without knowing that what it is doing earlier.

Comment: @SoulDenied, first, _which shell are you using?_ -- if it's happening during bash startup you'd use `PS4=':$BASH_SOURCE:$LINENO+' bash -x -l -i` to get a log of shell startup telling you what's being run that you can trawl through for alias commands; if it's zsh that you're sourcing the function with, then you'd need to find a zsh equivalent to that command (which I'm not the right person to help with -- and also, why are you tagging a question "bash" about a script when you actually source that script with zsh?)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy The first line of the question says they're using `zsh` -- that's the default shell on MacOS. And the error message they're getting is particular to zsh.

Comment: @Barmar, right; that's why I'm trying to prod them to also fix the title and tagging. If they'd properly tagged this as a zsh question I never would have seen it and my life would have been happier.

Comment: I already fixed the tag for them, didn't notice the title error.

Comment: Why does the alternative way of defining a function help here? Is there a difference, whether or not I explicitly use the `function` keyword?

Comment: Yes, because when the first word on a line is the name of an alias, it's expanded. If you write `function gss`, it's not the first word, so it's left alone.